# Mask an input on appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I have a phone input on my app:

```
<TextField id="FieldTelefone" class="textArea"></TextField>
```

I want to creat a telephone mask, preferably with REGEX, but I am having a hard time to do so on appcelerator.

I need it to be:
(xx)_xxxx-xxxx
or
(xx)_xxxx-xxxxx

the brazilian phone numbers pattern.

but I am not being able to do it with only javascript, I could however validate it, could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This git repo will help you: https://github.com/Nyvra/titanium-appcelerator-fields-mask

You surely have to extend the script, but there you'll see how it works

Comment: I am trying but it seems to not work quite well with the Regex, I am trying a few custom markups and it is not quite right yet, the operator | seems not to be working.